# Apache Flink: Read data from Kafka as byte array

Tags: deserialization, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

How can I read data from Kafka in `byte[]` format?

I have an implementation that reads events as `String` with `SimpleStringSchema()`  but I couldn't find a schema to read data as `byte[]`.

Here is my code:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "kafka1:9092");
    properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "zookeeper1:2181");
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");
    properties.setProperty("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    DataStream<byte[]> stream = env
                .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<byte[]>("testStr", ? ,properties));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found that:

```
DataStream<byte[]> stream = env
            .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>("testStr", new AbstractDeserializationSchema<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public byte[] deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                    return bytes;
                }
            }, properties));
```

Comment: It's work, may you create a PR to Flink Github repository.

Comment: It's not an issue, but it should be a utility Deserialize class.
I sure that so many people need it whenever work with byte array source.

Answer (score 0):

For scala you should write as following

```
new AbstractDeserializationSchema[Array[Byte]](){
     override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = bytes
}
```